# Use meta box value in CPT as post title

Tags: metabox

This has been addressed in [another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12056/automatically-set-post-title-to-same-value-as-a-meta-box), but the solution was too specific to apply here.

My goal is to use a metabox value (ecpt_name) as the post title so that the user only needs to input their name once, and the name appears in both the admin post listing and online.

As it is now, I require the user to input the post title as the full name AND in a metabox. This allows me to display the fullname online and show the fullname in the admin post listing, but it's double the work.

Looking for something to put into functions.php that hooks the ecpt_name metabox value and places it into the post_title name. thx - Steve

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );

function post_updated( $post_id ) {

    // verify post is not a revision & not an autosave
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && !(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) ) {
        // set the new post title
        $post['ID'] = $post_id;
        $post['post_title'] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ecpt_name', true);

        // update the post, removing the action to prevent an infinite loop
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
        wp_update_post($post);
        add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe check for DOING_AUTOSAVE constant being defined too? If not handled by post revision function above?

Comment: I totally forgot about that, thanks a lot. Updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply. Had to clarify that I need this only to affect a certain CPT, not all posts in general. Modified per below. However, the old post title still shows up in the admin post listing. Have to find a solution for that.

```
// draw post title from name metabox on CPT student

add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );

function post_updated( $post_id ) {

// affect only CPT student
if ($post_type == 'student') {
    // set the new post title
    $post['ID'] = $post_id;
    $post['post_title'] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ecpt_name', true);

    // update the post, removing the action to prevent an infinite loop
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
    wp_update_post($post);
    add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
}

}
```

Comment: you should include the `wp_is_post_revision` & `DOING_AUTOSAVE` checks as well, as i did in my answer, otherwise you might be updating a revision & not the main post